# Metal Gear Solid V TPP freezes PS3

Tags: ps3, metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I'm trying to play MGS5 on my ps3 but after the initial installation, it creates the savedata and then it freezes while on the loading screen (dualshock doesn't work, I have to shut it down by pressing the power button on the front). Not even the first cut scene is playing. Nothing at all. Is anybody experiencing the same problem? How can I possibly fix it? I've already tried to uninstall the data and delete the save. I've started it in offline mode too, but still no luck... Any help?

Comment: how much memory do you have available on your PS3? Have you downloaded all updates? This is apparently already a bunch of day one problems with the PlayStation and Computer versions of the game

Comment: I've got still 29GB left

Comment: Try deleting other files so you have more free space and see if that helps. I would have a hell of a lot of trouble playing such a large game with that much memory left on my console.. Remember, its designed for PS4.

Comment: I'll try! How much space do you think would be enough?

Comment: Can't say for sure. I would be removing anything I don't play anymore, but at about 100-150GB I would stop having troubles.

Comment: I'll try it this afternoon and I'll let you know! Thanks anyway

Comment: No luck with that either... Any other suggestion?